# How to stop root@<domain> getting emails for every PHP error

Tags: php

I set up a root@ email address on my server, then realized I was getting an email for every PHP error that happened. I'd like to disable this "log to email" functionality, but I can't find where to configure this.

(An aside, it's difficult to search for this issue since I just get php's mail() function help).

Where is php's email logging configured, and how do I disable/redirect it?

Comment: I think it partially depends on how the domain is set up. If you're hard-coded to email the wrong person or something and getting an error, you probably should change that. Otherwise, there may not be much you can do about it. It really depends on the context of what you're dong.

Comment: You might check to see if `error_log`'s value is set to `'syslog'` https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I checked it out and I don't have a value set for `error_log`. According to the docs: "If this directive is not set, errors are sent to the SAPI error logger." I'm going to investigate that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon a closer look at the emails I was getting, they were actually from `cron`, and not the php web scripts.

I changed the `MAILTO=` variable in my crontab to a different value and the emails stopped.